# Shading between two regions of two separate parametric curves/function

Tags: color, regions, parametric-functions

I have two long functions `g12` and `g14` in terms of `g2`:

```
g12 = √(-(30374999/480000) - g2^2 + 44401/(150000000 2^(2/3) (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625 + √(4 (-(231106915244401/390625) - (107745652224 g2^2)/625)^3 + (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) + (96294548 2^(1/3))/(125 (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625 + √(4 (-(231106915244401/390625) - (107745652224 g2^2)/625)^3 + (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) + (140293818 2^(1/3) g2^2)/(625 (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625 + √(4 (-(231106915244401/390625) - (107745652224 g2^2)/625)^3 + (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) + (1/(768 2^(1/3)))((7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625 + √(4 (-(231106915244401/390625) - (107745652224 g2^2)/625)^3 + (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)))
g14 = √(-(30374999/480000) - g2^2 - 34681467/(100000000 2^(2/3) (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625 + √(4 (-(231106915244401/390625) - (107745652224 g2^2)/625)^3 + (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) - (144441757 2^(1/3))/(375 (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625 + √(4 (-(231106915244401/390625) - (107745652224 g2^2)/625)^3 + (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) + (1150640 I 2^(1/3))/(Sqrt[3] (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625 + √(4 (-(231106915244401/390625) - (107745652224 g2^2)/625)^3 + (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) + (34681467 I Sqrt[3])/(100000000 2^(2/3) (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625 + √(4 (-(231106915244401/390625) - (107745652224 g2^2)/625)^3 + (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) + (203919 I 2^(1/3)Sqrt[3])/(125 (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625 + √(4 (-(231106915244401/390625) - (107745652224 g2^2)/625)^3 + (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) - (70146909 2^(1/3)g2^2)/(625 (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625 + √(4 (-(231106915244401/390625) - (107745652224 g2^2)/625)^3 + (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) + (70146909 I 2^(1/3) Sqrt[3] g2^2)/(625 (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625 + √(4 (-(231106915244401/390625) - (107745652224 g2^2)/625)^3 + (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) - (1/(1536 2^(1/3)))((7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625 + √(4 (-(231106915244401/390625) - (107745652224 g2^2)/625)^3 + (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) - (1/(512 2^(1/3) Sqrt[3]))I (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625 + √(4 (-(231106915244401/390625) - (107745652224 g2^2)/625)^3 + (7026667556070696253202/244140625 - (1637971061985345024 g2^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g2^4)/625)^2))^(1/3))
```

And I wish to plot two parametric curves by parameterizing `g2`:

```
ParametricPlot[{{g2, g12}, {g2, g14}}, {g2, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 2.5}}, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue], Directive[Orange]}, LabelStyle -> 12, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotPoints -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 20, Exclusions -> None, Frame -> True, FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

I arrive with:
[image]
Where the blue curve is represents `g12` and orange represents `g14`. I intend to **shade the area bounded by the blue curve, orange curve and the x-y axes**. How should I go about doing so?

Comment: Why not define explicitly as functions of `g2`: `g12[g2_] := (* stuff *); g14[g2_] := (* 
stuff *)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also works.

```
Plot[{g12, g14}, {g2, 0, 5.24}, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 2.5}}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {12, Black, Bold}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 20, Frame -> True, Filling -> {1 -> Axis, 2 -> {Axis, White}}]
```

[image]

For some reason, it is necessary to adjust the upper limit on `g2` to eliminate a faint vertical line.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Changed `PlotStyle` and `PlotRange`

```
{maxg2, maxy} = 
 Ceiling[{g2, g12} /. 
     NSolve[{g12 == g14, g2 > 0}, g2, WorkingPrecision -> 20][[1]] // 
    N // Chop, 0.05]

(* {5.25, 2.1} *)

Show[
 RegionPlot[{Re[g14] < y < Re[g12] && 0 < g2 < 6}, {g2, 0, maxg2}, {y,
    0, maxy},
  PlotStyle -> LightGreen,
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  BoundaryStyle -> None],
 ParametricPlot[{{g2, g12}, {g2, g14}}, {g2, 0, 10},
  PlotRange -> {{0, maxg2}, {0, maxy}},
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue], Directive[Orange]},
  LabelStyle -> 12,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  WorkingPrecision -> 20,
  Exclusions -> None,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black],
  PlotRangePadding -> None,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"g12", "g14"}, {0.35, 0.65}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Just a few follow up questions: It seems even with `PlotRangePadding->None` there still exists padding in the plot. Is there any way to remove the padding? Also how would I go about changing the color of the shade? (say Grey to Green) **Edit**: I figured out the color. I would just do `PlotStyle->`(color)